# Hiding label and show loading

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I need a image to swap when clicking on a button.

For that I'm using following action:

```
-(IBAction)randomize:(id)sender {
int randomimages = rand() % 2;
switch (randomimages) {
    case 0:
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"videre-btn.png"];
        break;
}}
```

in my storyboard I got the button assigned with the randomized action.

What I need is the button to vanish / fade out for 5-10 seconds after clicking on the action, and then appear back on screen after the time has gone.

Ideally I would like the iOS loading icon to show instead for the amount of time, but if anyone can help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: For the fading I would look into the UIView animateWithDuration: methods (see the UIView docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) and animate the opacity. For the loading icon that is a UIActivityIndicatorView (see the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing a loading icon look at [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

It lets you show many types of HUDs.

To show just a spinner you can then do

```
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:onView animated:YES];
```

And to remove it once done,

```
   [[MBProgressHUD allHUDsForView:onView] count];
```

I have created a category on my view controller that lets me show messages on any view. See [here](https://github.com/hackerinheels/ImageUtils).